# How to define function in external file?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build, build.gradle

I am experiencing a strange behaviour of gradle / groovy.

I have a `bulid.gradle` that looks like that:

```
def elastic(notation, projectName) {
   if (allprojects.find { it.name == projectName }) {
      println "adding project dependency on project $projectName"
      project(projectName)
   } else { 
      println "adding binary dependency on project $projectName"
      dependencies.create(notation)
   }
}

dependencies {
   elastic('my.group:myProject:1.0','myProject')
}
```

This function returns a binary dependency if there is no project with the name `myProject` otherwise it returns a project-dependency.
But that is not the point. I use this function quiet a lot in different projects and it works well. But to avoid redundant code i tried to externalize that function. So I put it into `define_elastic_1.gradle` and applyed that file to my `build.gradle`. Now it looks like that:

```
apply from: "file://entw1/ENTWICKLUNG/GfOPGradleRepo/define_elastic_1.gradle"
dependencies{
    elastic('my.group:myProject:1.0','myProject')
}
```

but when i do a `gradle build` it says

```
Could not find method elastic() for arguments [my.group:myProject:1.0, myProject] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Do you know why I can not use a function that is defined i a separate file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to define the function as a closure and via `ext` in `define_elastic_1.gradle`:

```
ext.elastic = { notation, projectName ->
   if (allprojects.find { it.name == projectName }) {
      println "adding project dependency on project $projectName"
      project(projectName)
   } else {
      println "adding binary dependency on project $projectName"
      dependencies.create(notation)
   }
}
```

Comment: @Mr.H., because both files (scripts) have different `this` object but the same `ext` - which is shared.

Comment: It's complicated. But basically a script gets compiled into a class of type `Script` and the body of the script goes into the class's `run()` method (or equivalent). The method you define becomes a sibling method of `run()`. So `run()` in the _define_elastic_ script can see the `elastic()` method, but `run()` in the main script cannot. Global variables/properties via `ext` do not suffer this limitation.

Comment: Reusable code like this should really go in the _buildSrc_ directory: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources . In this case, you could define `elastic()` as a static method of a utility class that you create and define in _buildSrc_.

Comment: Or, it the code is used in multiple project it should go to a separate plugin.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this function should be associated with the [DependencyHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html) rather than the [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) as suggested by @opal

Eg:

```
dependencies.ext.elastic = { notation, projectName ->
   // do stuff
} 
dependencies {
    elastic('my.group:myProject:1.0','myProject')
}
```

Comment: Might be as well, thanks! The question was about idea of using such function than place it should be declared.